# Spring Boot Rest application: Testing JDBC DAO layer

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, dao, spring-jdbc

How can I test my `DAO` layer in `Spring Boot Application` if my application only selects information from database and doesn't write anything?

Even more, my application selects data from view.

The common approach is to write some testing data by method with annotation `@BeforeEach` and to delete them by method with annotation `@AfterEach`.

But because my application performs query to view, I can't insert any data in database.

Is there any opportunity to test my `DAO` layer?

Comment: You should test it in test database where you can insert data in tables you need and create view you need to test

Comment: Look into using a MySQL TestContainer, populate it with data, and then your app will work as is for your Integration Test.

However if this is a Unit Test you are considering, then I would just mock the responses for `get` for example

Comment: Right you can not insert into a view....  You insert into the tables the view is built from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. Use an embedded [H2 database](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-h2-database) then seed it with a [data.sql](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-data-sql-and-schema-sql), which you can dump from your test database.
2. Use [DBUnit](https://www.baeldung.com/java-dbunit) and define your data in an xml file.

For you I think data.sql is the way to go. Just add a data.sql to your test/resources file and it will be picked up by JPA.